# draw a connected line between the gridview cells?

Tags: c#, wpf, gridview

Does anyone know how to draw a connected line between the cells in the gridview? I want to connect the lowest price of the fruits in each month. I am using WPF and C# to build it.

Here is the link for the picture of my situation I want my gridview to show :

[image]

P/s: I drew the image using Paint. Sorry, I couldn't upload a picture due to low reputation points.

Comment: hmm.....can you show me some example? thx

Answer (score 0):

Add a canvas like this to your xaml so that it fulfill your gridview

```
<Canvas Width="300" Height="300" Background="Beige"  Opacity="0.5" Name="canvas1"/>
```

then in your code, you can draw your path using either `Line` or `Path` class. My code is using Line class:

```
private void drawGridLines()
{
    Line lastline = new Line();
    lastLine.X2 = 0;
    lastLine.Y2 = 0;

    bool first = true;


    for(int i=0; i<5; i++) // iterate over your gridview rows
    {
        Line newline = new Line();

        newline.X1 = lastline.X2;
        newline.Y1 = lastline.Y2;

        newline.X2 = 50; // calculate X position of your minimum cell
        newline.Y2 = 50; // calculate Y position of your minimum cell 


        if(!first) { // first minimum cell should't be drawn, it is just the start point for next line

           drawLine(newline);
        } else {
           first = false;
        }

        lastline = newline;
    }
}

public void drawLine(Line line)
{
    line.Stroke = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Red;
    line.StrokeThickness = 1;
    canvas1.Children.Add(line);
}
```